# Renting an apartment in Austria: what is a "double broker"?

Tags: rental, austria, housing

The rental agreement for an apartment I would like to rent in Vienna, Austria mentions that the agent acting for the landlord is a "double broker":

> Weiters ist festzuhalten, dass das Maklerunternehmen aufgrund des bestehenden Geschäftsgebrauches als Doppelmakler tätig ist.

What is a double broker and what are the implications for the prospective tenant?

Comment: This seems like a legal question.

Comment: Perhaps. Do you know the answer?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

TL/DR: It's normal.

A "normal" non-doppel Makler, when tasked with finding people to buy/rent a realty, is basically a salesperson with the goal to make the landlord happy (and not you).

A Doppelmakler, on the other hand, wants to be a neutral middleman who tries to find the best fit for both sides, and who will tell you all disadvantages of a certain property too, and/or recommend properties of other landlords.

Most Austrian Maklers in the realty business work as Doppelmakler.

Just for completeness: The word Makler alone doesn't necessarily imply realties for private persons. In other business areas, being a Doppelmakler isn't common, and of course not desired by the contractors.